# Key Differences and features of BW 6.X AND BWCE( Container Edition)

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I am new to BW6 and BWCE.I need to understand the key features in both and difference between BW6.X and BWCE.
Any kind of ppts or reference sources would be of great help. 
I need to migrate my existing BW5 code to either BW6 or BWCE and then completely move them to AWS (Amazon web services) .

So in this aspect I need to verify which is more efficient BW6 OR BWCE.
pls provide with any ppt or resources if possible.
Would be of grt help if so.
Thnks in advance

Answer (score 1):

BW6 is targeted for on-premise, BWCE is targeted for On-Premise, Public Cloud or Hybrid. BWCE allows you to deliver your SW by CI/CD using maven and docker / kubernetes.

You have ton of videos in youtube about BWCE, this is specially good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VISNxgB74Bg